# Variable initialization in C++: a unique method

Tags: c++, initialization

Recently I came across this piece of code. I don't know why I never saw this kind of syntax in all my "coding life".

```
int main()
{
    int b;
    int a = (b=5, b + 5);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

a has value of 10. What exactly is this way of initialization called? How does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement:

```
int a = (b=5, b + 5);
```

Makes use of the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). Per Paragraph 5.18/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] **A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right**; the left expression is a discarded value
>   expression (Clause 5).83 Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
>   is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. **The type
>   and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand**; the result is of the same value category
>   as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand is a glvalue and a bit-field. If the value of the right
>   operand is a temporary (12.2), the result is that temporary.

Therefore, your statement is equivalent to:

```
b = 5;
int a = b + 5;
```

Personally, I do not see a reason for using the comma operator here. Just initialize your variable the easily readable way, unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise.

Comment: +1 for your last paragraph, this is just obfuscation IMHO and should be avoided whenever possible (which is, pretty much always). Out of the few mlocs I maintain along with my colleagues I don't think there is a single place where the comma operator is used, and I'd shamelessly do bodily harm to anyone daring to perpetrate that. Readability comes first.

Comment: @FoY: Oh, I see then. You won't find much of this code in real world applications anyway. And if you do, consider changing it (or suggesting to change it) into something more readable ;)

Answer (score 4):

operator `,` evaluates arguments one after another and return the last value

It may be used not only in initialization

Answer (score 3):

The comma `,` operator allows you to separate expressions. The compount statement made by

```
exp1, exp2, ..., expn
```

evaluates to `expn`.

So what happens is that first `b` is set to `5` and then `a` is set to `b + 5`.

**A side note**: since `,` has the lowest precedence in the table of operators the semantics of

```
int a = b = 5, b+5;
```

is different from

```
int a = (b = 5, b+5);
```

because the first is parsed as `(int a = b = 5), b + 5`

Answer (score 2):

When used in an expression the comma operator will evaluate all of its operands (left-to-right) and return the last.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization is called *copy initialization*. If you ignore the complex expression on the right, it's the same as in:

```
int a = 10;
```

This is to be contrasted with *direct initialization*, which looks like this:

```
int a(10);
```

(It's possible that you were separately confused about how to evalue a *comma expression*. Please indicate if that's the case.)

Comment: I actually meant the complex expression :) But it's all good, it's already answered.